# Is there a way to use Iptables to route a VPN image through a transparent proxy?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I have a docker image which houses a VPN. I'm trying to run that VPN through a transparent proxy (squid) before it reaches the web.
The proxy and docker image are on the same AWS instance. The ports are opened properly on AWS because I can confirm that, individually, the VPN and proxy work properly.

- VPN: I checked this by connecting to the VPN through a client connection.
- Proxy: I checked this by connecting through Firefox and looking at the squid access.log

When I try to configure the output of the VPN through the proxy I can no longer connect to the VPN through the client connection.
If I am already connected to the client through the VPN and make some changes to iptables, I can see output come across the access.log file and it looks like this:
*note, this is just a chunk of the output file that I copied and pasted. It all largely looks the same.

```
1657135083.310      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135083.317      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 - error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135083.469      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 e error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135085.108      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135085.109      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135085.596      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 s error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135088.298      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135103.475      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 - error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135103.604      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 - error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135103.733      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/400 3739 - error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1657135113.464      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135295.517      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135300.523      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135301.524      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135314.536      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135323.544      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135340.562      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135343.565      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1657135343.565      0 XX.XX.XX.XXX NONE_NONE/000 0 - error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
```

Here are the iptable rules when I run `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The output of `iptables -t nat -vnL` is:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3937  222K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   39  2340 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   12   664 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

My proxy is running on 3128 (just a standard squid proxy).

Including combinations of the following commands: (and adding in the port interface to each as well)

```
sudo iptables -t  nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport YYY -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport YYY -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o YYYY -j MASQUERADE
```

The moment I set any of the above iptable commands loose, I can no longer connect to the VPN. If I am already connected to the VPN I am unable to connect to any outside website. This leads me to believe that the connection is unable to get any responses from the Internet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you hide interface, ports and lan-ip names?

Comment: The first code block has the actual IP of the VPN commented out. Sure, you'd need a key to access it, but that was just to play it safe. I don't want to put an IP address out on the web for anyone to ping.  
The last code block was just the VPN port, but was hidden to be consistent.

Comment: Basically, 192.168,172.16 and 10/8 aren't route able and not ping able from outside, that's why I ask there is no reason to hide this, and the interfaces names are also non data protected since it is a required information and the names are all the same on all computers ;)